# E121: Undefined Variable: VundleInstalled & E15: Invalid Expression: VundleInstalled == 1 when running VIM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, vundle

I'm running through the upcase courses and they've introduced me to VIM which, with the help of tmux, is slowly replacing my use of Atom. I've been trying to use some simple plugins using Vundler and every time I run `Vim .` from my rails directory I get the following errors:

```
E121: Undefined variable: VundleInstalled
E15: Invalid expression: VundleInstalled == 1
```

I have been up and down this mean, mean internet and cannot find a solution to this issue.

My `~/.vimrc`

```
1 set number                                                                                        
2 set nocompatible
3 filetype off
4
5 syntax on
6 colorscheme Tomorrow-Night
7
8 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle.vim
9 call vundle#begin()
10
11 Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
12 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
13 Plugin 'wincent/command-t'
14 Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
15 Plugin 'vim-scripts/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}
16 Plugin 'tpope/vim-rails' 
17 Plugin 'tpope/vim-rake'
18 Plugin 'tpope/vim-bundler'
19 
20 " Color Schemes
21 Plugin 'chriskempson/tomorrow-theme'
22 Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
23 Plugin 'chriskempson/base16-vim'
```

The error I get occurs any time I try to open a file in VIM. On top of that, when I try and work in VIM I get the following message every time I try and open a directory or run a command:

`Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "*":                                       │Maximum connections set to 1024
E117: Unknown function: rails#buffer_setup`

Any help you could offer would be fantastic. I'm really digging VIM and tmux but I'm also discovering there's a bit of a learning curve to both of them.

Thanks!

Update: I have adjusted any issues with matching file names and, as far as I can tell it's not disrupting functionality. All the same, I would like to figure out why I"m getting this error.

Comment: https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/584

Comment: You are missing `call vundle#end()`.

Comment: Assuming I'm supposed to put this after all my Plugins, I saved that i my /.vimrc/ and still get the same error. I also removed a leftover vundler.vim file from when i tinkering around with VIM before. I deleted it in lieu of the most recent one, ran `:BundleUpdate` with no changes and `:BundleClear` wiped out everything that was in my `~/.vimrc` file.